# Why javascript function is not working although there are no errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phpbb3

here is the code:

```
<div id="one">
<div class="options-parameters-input">
This is testing
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Type font size</td>
    <td><textarea id="heretype"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

$("#heretype").on("keyup",both);

function both(){
$(".options-parameters-input").css("fontSize", this.value + "px");
}
```

link to jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/106/

So this code works in jsfiddle as you can see, but when i transfer this code to my phpBB theme, then for some unknown reason it does not work... and in Firefox Developer Tools there is no error.. So i dont know why is not working ? what could be a problem.

also

if i try to use `$("#heretype").addEventListener("keyup",both);`instead `.on`
then i receive error:

> TypeError: $(...).addEventListener is not a function

All javascript functions including this are stored in .js file called from footer.

also i have added `console.log($('#heretype').length);`

after that it just shows number 1 in console

please can you help me

Thank you

Comment: Are you running the code in a document.ready handler? Eg. `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: Are you actually embedding the javascript in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: To expand on what @RoryMcCrossan was saying, it depends on how phpBB hosts the code. If the scripts are elevated to the `<head>` of the document, you'll need to wrap the code in `$(function () { ... });` also referred to as a document ready block. Without this, the event will attempt to bind to an element that is not found on the page and will never execute. Note though that it also won't throw an error as in your case. To see if this is what is happening, add `console.log($('#heretype').length);` as the first statement in you script. Then run the script and check the console...

Comment: don't mix up jquery and javascript . addEventListener function belongs to javascript .

Comment: A *safer* document ready to use would be `jQuery(function($) { ... });` - this ensures that jQuery will still work even if it's in no-conflict mode.

Comment: all javascript functions are in .js file called from footer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the js part as a script by wrapping it within `<script>` tags like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$.noConflict();

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

    $("#heretype").on("keyup",both);
    function both(){
        $(".options-parameters-input").css("fontSize", this.value + "px");
    }
});

</script>
```

N.B. The `type="text/javascript"` is for backward compatibility but in new browsers, it's not really required anymore.

Comment: @cale_b: DOM Ready wrapper function not required if the script is included after the elements it references...

Comment: @GoneCoding - belt + suspenders.  I know it *may not be* required in this case, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @cale_b Thanks for the heads up. Edit made.

Comment: @cale_b: You forgot crash helmet, airbags and parachute (just in case) :)

Comment: @GoneCoding & cale_b So the docReady should be used or not?

Comment: It's safe to use.  I - as a matter of practice - always wrap my jQuery in no-conflict safe document ready, regardless of (a) whether the script is loaded in the header or footer, and (b) whether jQuery is running in no-conflict mode.  In this way, I am always confident that I don't have issues.  So - "Should be used" - IMO, yes.  "Necessary", *maybe* not.

Comment: But I would remove the `$.noConflict()`.  We don't need to force it to run in no-conflict mode, but your document ready (the way you have it) ensures that jQuery will work *if it IS* in noConflict mode.